# How do I make two ImageViews change several images simultaneously

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to build a dice rolling app in Android.

I managed to build my basic layout and methods with ease but I am currently stuck with the following issue:
I have two `ImageView`'s on my screen and I need to make them change simultaneously 3 times, a basic simulation of a dice rolling, before the final dice face is presented to the user.

So far I tried it this way:

```
    public void rollDiceAnim() {

        ////// diceone anim
        final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int counter = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (counter<4) {
                    counter++;
                    Log.e("Counter value",counter+"!");
                    int diceOneAnim = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                    ImageView dice1_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dice1_img);

                    switch (diceOneAnim) {
                        case 1:
                            dice1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d1);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dice1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d2);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            dice1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d3);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            dice1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d4);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            dice1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d5);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            dice1_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d6);
                            break;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 150);
                } else {
                    rollDice();
                }


            }
        };

    /////////

    ///// dice two anim
    final android.os.Handler handler2 = new android.os.Handler();
    Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
        int counter2 = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (counter2<4) {
                counter2++;
                Log.e("Counter value",counter2+"!");
                int diceTwoAnim = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                ImageView dice2_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dice2_img);

                switch (diceTwoAnim) {
                    case 1:
                        dice2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        dice2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        dice2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d3);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        dice2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d4);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        dice2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d5);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        dice2_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d6);
                        break;
                }
                handler2.postDelayed(this, 500);
            } else {
                rollDice();
            }


        }
    };
    ////////////////////////

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    handler2.postDelayed(runnable2, 100);

}
```

I have made two runnable objects, each iterating randomly, changing a set of dice faces before presenting the final one.

The problem is when running the two:

```
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    handler2.postDelayed(runnable2, 100);
```

They do not run at the same time. After the first handler is finished, the second handler still has some work to do.

I've tried using threads instead of handlers, but my app just crashes.

Comment: I think this code should not work, because you can set views only in main thread.

Comment: this code is working, that method rollDiceAnim() is being called in the main thread.
The behaviour i am trying to achieve is similar to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT5lZj5zdO4&t=0m15s
making the dice imageViews change at the same time several times to simulate a basic dice roll.

Comment: `They do not run at the same time. After the first handler is finished, the second handler still has some work to do.` this is how multi-threading suppose to work! Also post your stack trace in your question.

Comment: I am unsure why i should post my stacktrace, i mean i don`t have any error or exception being thrown, everything works with the code i posted above the only thing is i am not achieving the desired result, check the youtube video i posted in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try combining that two jobs into a same `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest checking out the Android API about AsyncTask. It a better way to work with asynchronous request especially if you have more than one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion, will check and come back here